# How to collect specified monomials in polynomial?

Tags: syntax, polynomials

I'm not experienced in Wolfram Language, so couldn't you please help me with its syntax? Given the polynomial expression:

```
poly = 59049 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 1, 1] + 
  32805 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 1, 2] + 
  7290 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 1, 3] + 
  810 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 1, 4] + 
  45 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 1, 5] + 
  Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 1, 6] - 
  59049 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 2, 1] - 
  32805 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 2, 2] - 
  7290 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 2, 3] - 
  810 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 2, 4] - 
  45 Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 2, 5] - 
  Subscript[B, 1] Subscript[Abx, 2, 6] - 59049 Subscript[Aby, 1, 1] - 
  32805 Subscript[Aby, 1, 2] - 7290 Subscript[Aby, 1, 3] - 
  810 Subscript[Aby, 1, 4] - 45 Subscript[Aby, 1, 5] - 
  Subscript[Aby, 1, 6] + 59049 Subscript[Aby, 2, 1] + 
  32805 Subscript[Aby, 2, 2] + 7290 Subscript[Aby, 2, 3] + 
  810 Subscript[Aby, 2, 4] + 45 Subscript[Aby, 2, 5] + 
  Subscript[Aby, 2, 6]
```

and the list:

```
subs = {Subscript[Abx, 2, 4], Subscript[Abx, 2, 5], 
  Subscript[Abx, 2, 6], Subscript[Aby, 2, 1], Subscript[Aby, 2, 2], 
  Subscript[Aby, 2, 3], Subscript[Aby, 2, 4], Subscript[Aby, 2, 5], 
  Subscript[Aby, 2, 6]}
```

I need to collect the coefficients of monomials of the polynomial, that contain the variables from the list. So the answer should be:

```
{-810 Subscript[B, 1], -45 Subscript[B, 1], -Subscript[B, 
  1], 59049, 32805, 7290, 810, 45, 1}
```

I know how to do this using a lot of "For" and "If" constructions, but I know that it is not advisable because Wolfram Language has very powerful, beautiful and fast-acting built-in functions. Can you please help me and write, how to solve my problem with the most efficient way? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
Last@CoefficientList[poly, #] & /@ subs
```

> ```
> {-810 Subscript[B, 1], -45 Subscript[B, 1], -Subscript[B, 
>   1], 59049, 32805, 7290, 810, 45, 1}
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
Normal @ Last @ CoefficientArrays[poly, subs]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!